# Reference Points To Anchor Points? (Newbie)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, app-store, coronasdk

can you please help me with the following. I'm converting an app built with a previous version of Corona. It keeps telling me "object:setReferencePoint() is only available in v1Compatibility mode. Use anchor points instead."

```
_G.buttonShowInfo = display.newImageRect( _G.imagePath.."info.png", display.contentWidth*0.12, display.contentHeight*0.08)
--_G.buttonShowInfo:setReferencePoint( display.BottomLeftReferencePoint )
_G.buttonShowInfo:setReferencePoint( display.BottomRightReferencePoint )
```

I tried switching it to the following, but no luck.Could you point me in the right direction?

```
_G.buttonShowInfo = display.newImageRect( _G.imagePath.."info.png", display.contentWidth*0.12, display.contentHeight*0.08)
_G.buttonShowInfo:info.anchorX = 0.0;
_G.buttonShowInfo:info.anchorY = 1.0;
```

Comment: bottom right is 1, 1 not 0, 1

Comment: @Lukis you should reply with that as a possible answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I reckon that the second code block would be:

```
_G.buttonShowInfo = display.newImageRect( _G.imagePath.."info.png", display.contentWidth*0.12, display.contentHeight*0.08)
_G.buttonShowInfo.anchorX = 0.0;
_G.buttonShowInfo.anchorY = 1.0;
```

(There was an :info not needed)

Also, for a project I needed to migrate, I created this function which covers most often used reference points conversions, it can help in some specific cases where you cannot just go and replace every single reference points usages (it was the case in mine). If you need a reference point not listed well it's easy to add :) :

```
    function referenceToAnchor(oReferencePoint)
     local nAnchorX = 0.0
     local nAnchorY = 0.0

     if oReferencePoint == display.TopLeftReferencePoint then
        nAnchorX = 0.0
        nAnchorY = 0.0
     elseif oReferencePoint == display.CenterReferencePoint then
        nAnchorX = 0.5
        nAnchorY = 0.5
     elseif oReferencePoint == display.BottomLeftReferencePoint then
        nAnchorX = 0.0
        nAnchorY = 1.0
     elseif oReferencePoint == display.BottomRightReferencePoint then
        nAnchorX = 1.0
        nAnchorY = 1.0
     end    
     return nAnchorX, nAnchorY
    end
```